# Fortran operations on multidimensional arrays - sum example

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am trying to figure how to do simple algebraic operations on a subset of elements in a multidimensional array and assign the result to another array with the same dimensions.

```
program hello
IMPLICIT NONE
   REAL,DIMENSION(10,10,2,1) :: tmp1=2
   REAL,DIMENSION(10,10,2,1) :: tmp2=1
   INTEGER,DIMENSION(2) :: myind=(/1,2/)
```

This operations returns only one value

```
Print *, sum(tmp1(:,:,itree,:))
```

While this returns the correct results, however I would expect the same result than the second operation, maybe I am thinking in the R way.

```
Print *, tmp1(:,:,1,:)+tmp1(:,:,2,:)
end program Hello
```

How do I achieve the result of the second operation and assign it to another multidimensional array? Imagine my index is large so I can't type out each single term in the operation.

Comment: *however I would expect the same result,* Which one? Did you want to use the `dim=` argument?

Comment: @VladimirF I would like the result to contain as many values as elements in the array, not one single value. Does it make sense?

Comment: As is the number of elements in which array? And all of the values should contain what? Sum of all elements of the original array and all the same or each should be different? An example would really help, especially if you believe it is not a duplicate of those two questions I linked.

Comment: @VladimirF yes that was the solution. But how would you do there are two operations such as SUM(array1*array2) always for a specific rank?

Comment: The same way. If I understand what you want to do. You really have to specify your problems more clearly and in more detail.